# дискретный алгоритм укладки рюкзака. out of range

Tags: python-3.x, динамическое-программирование

```
def rukz(m,v,M):# вес рукзака
n=len(m)-1 # количество вещей


F = [ [0] * (n + 1) for i in range(M + 1)]
for i in range(1, n +1):
    for k in range(1, M+1 ):
        if k >= m[i]:
            F[k][i] = max(F[k][i-1], F[k-m[i]][i - 1] + v[i])
        else:
            F[k][i] = F[k][i-1]    

m=[0,5,10,6,5] # масса 
v=[0,3,5,4,2] # стомость
M=14 # вес рюкзака
rukz(m,v,M)
```

Дискретный алгоритм укладки рюкзака. выдает ошибку:
line 20, in rukz
if k >= m[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range

не понимаю почему? массив двумерный создан. 5/15. перебирает с 1 по 4 / с 1 по 14. в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    ...
        if k >= m[i]:
```

У Вас `i` изменяется от `1` до `4`, a индексы в массиве `m` идут от `0` до `3`.

За границы двумерного массива `F` Вы вылезете в следующих строчках.

Comment: не понимаю( по i  -  4 итерации от 1 по 4. и в массиве 4 индекс с 0 по 3... где выходит за границы?

Comment: @Alex За границы выходит m[4].

Comment: что нужно поменять тогда?

Comment: хэлп). из вики один в один ж https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5 (задача 0-1)

Comment: все разобрался. нужно добавить нули в массивы данных, чтобы сравнение шло по индексам.